# add new lines when generating xml from object

Tags: c#, xml

this is the code

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("customers");
xml.AppendChild(root);
foreach (var cust in customerlist)
{
    XmlElement child = xml.CreateElement("customer");
    child.SetAttribute("CustomerId", cust.CustomerId.ToString());
    child.SetAttribute("CustomerName", cust.CustomerName);
    child.SetAttribute("PhoneNumber", cust.PhoneNumber);
    child.SetAttribute("Email", cust.Email);
    root.AppendChild(child);
}
string s = xml.OuterXml;
```

I want my string to have next lines added to it instead of a single xml document

My string is coming as continuous

> < x >xxxxx< /x > < x >xxxxx< /x >

Comment: What is your problem here specifically?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, please add more details to what you mean by "have next lines added to it"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I meant '\n'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [XmlTextWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) class to format the XML as a string like this:

```
StringWriter string_writer = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xml_text_writer = new XmlTextWriter(string_writer);
xml_text_writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xml.WriteTo(xml_text_writer); // xml is your XmlDocument

string formattedXml = string_writer.ToString();
```

Comment: Well nothing, but you wanted your XML string formatted and that's how you can do it with a `XmlTextWriter `. Just try it and put my example after your code in the question and output the `formattedXml ` string instead of your `s`.

Comment: What is the difference between XmlWriter and XmlTextWriter?

Comment: `XmlWriter` is the *abstract* base class of `XmlTextWriter`, you can't use that.

Comment: @Breathing it should work, can you update your question with the added code and how you display the string? The code in my answer is pretty complete, you just have to add if after your XML generation and replace your line `string s = xml.OuterXml;` with `string s = string_writer.ToString();`.

Comment: Thank you so much! :')

I want my final string to be something like `<x>{0}{1}</x> which then I can use string format to put in values.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Since I am first creating xml here then converting string. What can I do about this?

Comment: @Breathing I think you should create another question for that, but when you already have the values like in your question above I'm not sure why you would create a placeholder and replace the values later. Or better describe what data you have and what you want to do and not only what you have tried so far. But as I said better create a new question for that.

Comment: Why is this not getting formatted
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/185c7fbdcabb499bbe34a4249a76b309/raw/9d4bcca29aece54c2cc30d0028c134e9a79c7104/format

Comment: can you help out with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618484/not-getting-xml-portion-in-formatted-form?noredirect=1#comment84236146_48618484